# Catching an exception for a SQL connection in Perl

Tags: perl

Using the Ensembl Perl [API](http://www.ensembl.org/info/docs/Doxygen/core-api/classBio_1_1EnsEMBL_1_1Registry.html#a7e564f1b1bf7d176041f700713a7c1bf), there is a `load_registry_from_db` function which connects to a SQL server. It is stated that it will throw an exception for connection timeouts.

```
 $registry->load_registry_from_db(
  -host    => 'ensembldb.ensembl.org',
  -user    => 'anonymous',
  -verbose => '1'
);
```

> Exceptions : Thrown if the given MySQL database cannot be connected to
>                  or there is any error whilst querying the database.

I want to know how can I catch that exception via Perl? It is written on the pages that `eval` is the best thing. Is that `eval {$registry}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely use [eval](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html):

```
my $statement_ok = eval {
    $registry->load_registry_from_db(
        -host    => 'ensembldb.ensembl.org',
        -user    => 'anonymous',
        -verbose => '1'
    );
    1;
};

if (! $statement_ok){
    # handle error
    do_something() if $@ =~ /.../;
}
```

The reason I prefer doing it this way is that something else may have or can clobber `$@`, so using the true statement will ensure that even if `$@` is somehow already set, you're sure to have trapped the specific exception in that code.

Essentially, if the call doesn't throw, `$statement_ok` will be true.

You can also use an external library such as [Try::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Try::Tiny), but I must admit, I've never used such a thing, I've always just stuck with `eval`.

Comment: So... That Perl script is called from a Java code via `final Process p = pb.start();    int exitCode = p.waitFor();`. Will your code returns the exit number to its parent?

Comment: No, but you can force it to, by using something like `exit -1;` etc. within the `if (! $statement_ok){...}`

Comment: *"The reason I prefer doing it this way"* For this to have any value you need to explain *what you prefer it to*.

Comment: Once you're working in modern Perl, and your code is not running as a CGI script, using Try::Tiny is going to be the cleaner way. It makes reading the code way easier. It adds a few levels to the call stack, but that's usually not a problem. Knowing how this stuff works under the hood is good and valuable, but I'd (almost) always go with the easier to maintain solution.

Comment: @simbabque I understand your point of view. I just always write my code so it runs all the way back to 5.8 and as close to core-only as I can. I will re-write this post for more modern Perl for the general masses, and to address Borodin's statement above. Thanks for the feedback.